# Neural network graph visualization

Tags: pytorch

I would like to generate visualization of my neural network (PyTorch or ONNX model) similar to [this](https://www.graphcore.ai/posts/what-does-machine-learning-look-like) using Graphcore Poplar.
I have looked in the [documentation](https://docs.graphcore.ai/en/latest/) but I cannot find where this visualization feature is.

How can I achieve such a task ? Is there any other existing library ?

Answer (score 2):

that visualization is not part of the Graphcore Poplar software. It is "data art" generated by the team at GraphCore.

It is a tough work and requires many hours to get to that fine quality, but if you are decided, I would suggest to start looking at graph visualization tools looking for "graph network visualization" (and get inspiration from galleries like https://cytoscape.org/screenshots.html).

The NN architecture can be converted into a common graph format (neurons as nodes, connections as edges) and then you may start trying.

Some ideas:
Start with a simple NN with three layers. Place the input layer at the outer circle, there is a inner circle for the hidden layer and the output layer is placed in the center. Each neuron is a dot, with radius relative to the weight and color with the bias, and you can displace it towards/away the neurons in the previous layers based on the weight. Check this image for inspiration if you are looking for a "biological" style: https://cytoscape.org/images/screenshots/edge_bundling3_1400px.png